# OBIEE 12C multiple conditional formatting

Tags: xml, obiee

I am trying to combine multiple conditional formats in OBIEE. I need to change the background color of a field in a pivot table based on 2 rules. I used this tutorial (http://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2014/03/the-secret-life-of-conditional-formatting-in-obiee/) to change this in the xml. However the "AND" relationship doesn't seem to work. I tried changing it to "OR" and both my rules were evaluated and worked separately. What am I doing wrong? I know for a fact that the tests work separately. The first one tests if a column equals to null, the second one tests if a column value is equal to the letter T.

Here is my xml code for this column:

```
<saw:conditionalDisplayFormat>
                 <saw:formatRule>
                    <saw:condition>

                        <sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:logical" op="and">
                           <sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:comparison" op="null">
                              <sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:columnRefExpr" columnID="cd59ed399a6f037eb"/>
                            </sawx:expr>
                            <sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:comparison" op="equal">
                                 <sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:columnRefExpr" columnID="c267e812e3cddb2f4"/>
                                 <sawx:expr xsi:type="xsd:string">T</sawx:expr>
                            </sawx:expr>
                        </sawx:expr></saw:condition>
                    <saw:formatSpec backgroundColor="#FF9900" wrapText="true"/></saw:formatRule></saw:conditionalDisplayFormat>
```

Comment: Can you show us all the XML inside the `<saw:conditionalDisplayFormat>` tags? Maybe you are missing some other piece in that tag.

Comment: Hi Mark, I've put the requested part above in my question.

Comment: Nothing incorrect jumps out. I would test with an example where both comparisons being carried out are `equal` comparisons. If that doesn't work, perhaps something changed between 11g and 12c that prevents this from working. I'm on 11.1.1.7. I'm going to go test it out now.

Comment: This is right! I tried it and it worked, but my problem is not solved. I have a column which has NULL values so I don't think I can test on equal null? What datatype should that be?

Comment: Could you do an `IFNULL` and change all nulls to 0, then do equal to 0? I don't know your data so that may not work in this case. I'm going to do a test in 11.1.1.7 on a null comparison type.

Comment: When you were trying this before, were you getting any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

I got my example to work in OBIEE 11.1.1.7.140527 with the following XML Code:

```
<saw:conditionalDisplayFormats>
<saw:conditionalDisplayFormat>
    <saw:formatRule>
        <saw:condition>
            <sawx:expr op="equal" xsi:type="sawx:comparison">
                <sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:columnRefExpr" columnID="c0d250507b6b80abe"/>
                <sawx:expr xsi:type="xsd:decimal">18</sawx:expr></sawx:expr>
        </saw:condition>
            <saw:formatSpec backgroundColor="#FF0000" wrapText="true"/>
    </saw:formatRule>
</saw:conditionalDisplayFormat>
<saw:conditionalDisplayFormat>
    <saw:formatRule>
        <saw:condition>
            <sawx:expr op="equal" xsi:type="sawx:comparison">
                <sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:columnRefExpr" columnID="ca67cc42b11c6301a"/>
                <sawx:expr xsi:type="xsd:string">EXW</sawx:expr></sawx:expr>
        </saw:condition>
            <saw:formatSpec backgroundColor="#FFFF00" wrapText="true"/>
    </saw:formatRule>
</saw:conditionalDisplayFormat>
<saw:conditionalDisplayFormat>
    <saw:formatRule>
        <saw:condition>
            <sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:logical" op="and">
                <sawx:expr op="equal" xsi:type="sawx:comparison">
                    <sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:columnRefExpr" columnID="c0d250507b6b80abe"/>
                    <sawx:expr xsi:type="xsd:decimal">18</sawx:expr>
                </sawx:expr>
                <sawx:expr op="equal" xsi:type="sawx:comparison">
                    <sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:columnRefExpr" columnID="ca67cc42b11c6301a"/>
                    <sawx:expr xsi:type="xsd:string">EXW</sawx:expr>
                </sawx:expr>
            </sawx:expr>
        </saw:condition>
            <saw:formatSpec backgroundColor="#FF9900" wrapText="true"/>
    </saw:formatRule>
</saw:conditionalDisplayFormat>
</saw:conditionalDisplayFormats>
```

[image: pivot table with Orange]

Make sure you are just adding that piece of code after your two other conditions (red and yellow), not replacing them completely.

If your code matches mine, I would look into seeing if Oracle changed the XML formatting of the conditional formatting with the 12c release.

Comment: I tried this and this worked for me as well. The problem is I need at least one NULL condition. I made it so that the other condition also evaluated to NULL but two NULL's don't seem to work.

Comment: This is my try with NULL conditions: `<sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:logical" op="and">
                               <sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:comparison" op="null">
                                  <sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:columnRefExpr" columnID="cd59ed399a6f037eb"/>
                                </sawx:expr>
                                <sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:comparison" op=“null”>
                                     <sawx:expr xsi:type="sawx:columnRefExpr" columnID="c267e812e3cddb2f4”/>
                                </sawx:expr>
                            </sawx:expr>`

Comment: That all looks correct with me... I'm not sure why these XML updates wouldn't work with nulls, especially since we now know not using nulls allows it to work.

Comment: I've looked at it again and tested a few other things. The only thing that seems to bother is that one condition tests for a measure value and the other one tests for an attribute. The first one evaluated for all cells in my pivot table and the other one evaluates row per row. Could this be the problem (and how should I solve this)?